# I can't seem to make it find the average consonants/vowels after the user inputs it

Tags: python, average

This is the code I have so far. This program is supposed to ask the user for a word and determine the amount of vowels/consonants in it. After the user is done, the program is supposed to give them the average number of vowels/consonants. Some of the beginning code is different (different between `V` and `C`) because I was trying to figure out which would work

```
#Okay, this is the updated version of the code where I combined @AshwiniChaudhary 's code and mine
```

## Now I'm getting an IndexError: tuple index out of range

## I tried looking it up on here and a few other sites, but didn't really find the answer and I didn't want to ask the same question twice on here

```
print("Hello!")
import sys
import re


def VOCO():
VOCO = input("Search for VOWELS or CONSONANTS: ")

if VOCO == "VOWELS":
    VOW = input("Please input word for VOWEL counting: ")
    re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU]', VOW)
    V = int(len(re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU]', VOW)))
    print(V)


elif VOCO == "CONSONANTS":
    CON = input("Please input word for CONSONANT counting: ")
    re.findall(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]', CON)
    C = int(len(re.findall(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]', CON)))
    print(C)

else:
    print("Please use either VOWELS or CONSONANTS in selection.")
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
def find_vo_cons2(strs,val):
    vowels="aeiou"
    consonants=set(al)-set(vowels) #set containing only consonants   
    le=float(len(strs))

    vowel_count=0
    consonant_count=0

    for x in strs:
        if x.lower() in vowels:
            vowel_count+=1
        elif x.lower() in consonants:
            consonant_count+=1
    if val in ("V","v"):
        return vowel_count/le
    elif val in ("C","c"):
        return consonant_count/le


def CNT(): True or False
CNT = input("Would you like to continue (YES/NO)? ")

if CNT() : "YES"
condition(True)
VOCO()

else:
        strs = (VOW or CON)
        print("The average of {0} count is {1}".format(find_vo_cons2(strs,VOCO)))
        sys.exit
VOCO()
while True:
    VOCO()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do this without using `regex` as well:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
def find_vo_cons(strs,val):
    vowels="aeiou"
    consonants=set(al)-set(vowels) #set containing only consonants   
    le=float(len(strs))

    vowel_count=0
    consonant_count=0

    for x in strs:
        if x.lower() in vowels:
            vowel_count+=1
        elif x.lower() in consonants:
            consonant_count+=1

    if val in ("V","v"):
        return vowel_count/le
    elif val in ("C","c"):
        return consonant_count/le

def main():
    VOCO = input("Search for VOWELS(v) or CONSONANTS(c): ")
    dic={"v":"Vowels","c":"Consonants"}
    strs=  input("Enter the string: ")
    print ("The average of {0} count is {1}".format(dic[VOCO.lower()],find_vo_cons(strs,VOCO)))

main()
```

**output:**

```
~$ python3 so.py
Search for VOWELS(v) or CONSONANTS(c): v
Enter the string: foObAr
The average of Vowels count is 0.5

~$ python3 so.py
Search for VOWELS(v) or CONSONANTS(c): c
Enter the string: qwertyuiop
The average of Consonants count is 0.6
```

Comment: Would that go before my def VOCO() or after? I am confused about the order of things.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, I will make amends to my code using some of yours. I would +1 but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @BrandonJones You can do anything you want with this code. :)

Comment: I tried combining both of our codes and was almost successful with it, except I messed up on a tuple somewhere. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it either so any more help would be appreciated (:

Comment: @BrandonJones what is `CNT() == "NO"` doing in that `else` condition? 
And `CNT == input("Would you like to continue (YES/NO)? ")` is also wrong as you used `==` here.
Plus you're not returning values from any of your functions, so `CNT() == "YES"` is Never going to be True.

Comment: I just put 'CNT() == "NO"' in the else condition to complete it. There's not really a purpose for it I suppose. For 'CNT == input("Would you like to continue (YES/NO)? ")' , am I supposed to use the ':' instead of the '==' ?

Comment: @BrandonJones We use a `=` for assigning values and `==` for comparison, please look at some basic python tutorials and learn such things first.